# How to distinguish incoming urls on PHP in order to decide the action to be taken using an if statement

Tags: php, if-statement, url

I want to channel the the field's of different forms into different MYSQL tables depending on what page (i.e internal pages) they are coming from with an if statement. but I don't know how to determine the which page is submitting the form. I don't want to write a diff query for each form. I want all the diff form requests to be handled in one place.

I came across this

```
$URL_REF = parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
$URL_REF_HOST =   $URL_REF['host'];
```

but I don't know how to use it...

would want to get the incoming url into a variable like $inURL and then use it in an if statement like this:

```
if ($inURL == "pagename"){

}
```

pls help

Comment: `I don't want to write a diff query for each form`...then use a shared function which can be `include`d in all the pages which need it. Far easier than trying to work out where things came from.

Comment: Depending on hosting service (IIS, apache, nginx) you should be able to rewrite all inbound requests to some controller.

Comment: @ADyson I'll consider this option. Thanks alot

Comment: @user3783243 I'll also consider this option as well. Thanks a lot